# Slight difference in the meaning I cannot understand

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

I am working on a text regarding quality of computational systems. I am following an ISO standard where I found:

> Verification Process is to confirm that each software work product
>   and/or service of a process or project properly **reflects** the specified
>   requirements.

And

> Validation Process is to confirm that the requirements for a specific
>   intended use of the software work product are **fulfilled**.

I cannot spot the difference. The former checks whether it reflects requirements, the latter whether it fulfilled requirements. I would say that reflect requirement is like follow them=fulfill? Obviously not.
Thanks

Comment: You can Google the "difference between validation and verifiction" and get several much better explanations than these two terrible sentences.

Comment: @PeterShor: What you said. "Are we building the [right product?](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/verification-vs-validation/) Are we building the [product right?](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/verification-vs-validation/)"

Comment: Actually no, because this is the ISO standard. On the internet there is a lot of confusion what is validation and verification. Some think verification is testing, which is not (according to ISO) etc. Even the books are contradicting on this topic, I did very extensive research.

Comment: The proper definition of the terms is out of the scope of ELU. It is only the meaning of the sentences you provided that is relevant.

Comment: Kris: exactly. And I still cannot see the difference between "ensuring it does what requirements say" and "ensuring it does it completely". The first sentence use the word reflect instead of, e.g. conform to.

Comment: The difference in terms of technical English, I believe, is that a *"software work product"* is not just the final piece of software, but includes all the plans for designing and building the piece of software. So according to my interpretation of these sentences, verification isn't concentrating on the  actual piece of software that results; it's ensuring that the process for designing and building it will produce a piece of software conforming to the specifications. And *validation* is ensuring that this process is actually properly followed. Does the ISO define "software work product"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(If anyone wants to see the full original context, [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Li_JzmrWfkwC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22Verification%20Process%20is%20to%20confirm%20that%20each%22&source=bl&ots=vPNFFtr3wr&sig=0P4wIlHaFsGIURp1eEO1ILFVGqM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rq-OUJeXFePO0QX3-4G4DQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22Verification%20Process%20is%20to%20confirm%20that%20each%22&f=false) seems to be it.)

I think OP is simply being misled by *"requirements"* appearing in both definitions, together with the fact that *specified* is in the first, and *specific* in the second. Reading the full text, it's obvious...

> **Verification** = *ensuring the software addresses everything in the **specified requirements***.
>
> **Validation** = *ensuring the software addresses the **specified intended use***.

An example of the difference arose a few years ago in a company I had dealings with. The customer (a nationwide group encompassing many bus companies) wanted to store *all* their bus ticket data within a single centrally-maintained industry-standard [RDBMS](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=RDBMS&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=hLeOUM65Iqe_0QWtgoGwAg&ved=0CCAQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c68e77c4cb438b30&bpcl=35466521&biw=1206&bih=866) database. But the requirements specification said nothing about *speed of processing*.

After a development team had spent over a year producing a system which seemed to meet the specification, it became apparent that on any hardware the customer could realistically hope to afford, loading each new day's data would probably take more than 24 hours.

One could of course say this debacle was caused by a deficient specification - but such mistakes are bound to happen sometimes. And that's what OP's "validation" process is supposed to catch.

---

EDIT: It seems OP isn't satisfied with my way of describing the difference, so I'll quote from the start of the chapter I linked to above...

> [verification is] “Confirmation that work products properly ***reflect the requirements specified*** for them”. In other words, verification ensures that “you built it right”.
>
> [validation is] “Confirmation that the product, as provided (or as it will be provided) will ***fulfill its intended use***”. Therefore, validation ensures that 'you built the right product'.

(italics mine)

Comment: thanks, however, ISO considers testing only as validation. How would you check that SW addresses specified requirements? Verification is only static checking of design, code, documents..but not running the program

Comment: @Riawe: I'm not sure where you get *"ISO considers testing only as validation"* from. Are you perhaps making assumptions about what the words *testing*, *validation* and *verification* actually ***mean***, according to dictionaries? For the fine distinction being made in your example, I don't think dictionary definitions are relevant. The words you should pay attention to are those I highlighted above (***specified requirements*** and ***specified intended use***), not the ones you highlighted (***reflects*** and ***fulfilled***).

Comment: If you check the ISO, then verification activities are requirement verification, design verification, code verification. Validation activities: testing (stress, boundary...). Verification focuses only on the "software work product", not software itself. Also you can verify that design document describes what requirement contains, and its traceable to code etc. But in validation, you check the final product and test it if it works as intended.

Comment: Your edit makes sense, yet you kept the "software" in the verification defition in the beginning of your post. Verification cares about work products, if they conforms to specs.

Comment: @Riawe: I'm only following your source (which admits it's a paraphrasing of the ISO standard, ***not*** the exact original text of the ratified standard itself). Since your source actually refers to the *"software work product"* in both its paraphrased definitions, I left it that way because I thought that would be less confusing for you. It seems like you're still trying to justify interpretation according to *your existing* understanding of the terms, rather than reading the *exact, context-specific* definitions as supplied and used by your source.

Comment: I am sorry, but I use the original text from ISO standard. Verification deals with software work products while validation with product itself.

Comment: In other words, I cannot understand: if verification checks conformance with requirements, why the actual testing is validation activity? Isnt testing checking just that?

Comment: Well, I think I got it: Verification makes sure that requirements are followed during the whole development (design captures requirements, code follows the design, traceability..). When the product is built, validation makes sure the software as a whole conforms to requirements and can be used as intended.

Comment: @Riawe- Very good.  You've got it.  Verification - checks that requirements are implemented.  Validations - check that product is suitable for use.   I seem to remember typing that as an answer...

Comment: @Riawe: If you and Jim think you've got it, who am I to argue? I don't really understand much of your "re-statement", but ***can be used as intended*** is certainly crucial to "validation" rather than "verification", in this context.

Comment: @Jim Yes, I did comment your one. The only issue I have - during validation (actual testing) we do check functional specification which is requirements, so the intended use equals user requirements? An example: Requirement is to have a screen with buttons X,Y, allowing to Load and Save. Verification will make sure that elements are designed, coded, integrated. Validation, testing of the final product, will confirm the buttons are here and working.

Comment: @Riawe: I'm sorry, but I think you're completely missing the point. The ISO standard isn't directly concerned with details like the specifications that computer coders work to. Validation means that the system as a whole *does whatever job the customer expected it to do when he authorised the purchase*. It could be changed to a voice-activated system with no on-screen buttons at all, so long as it ***worked***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, iso 12207 is.. I mean, it says that verification ensures specified requirements are reflected, validation ensures that requirements for intended use are fulfilled = business requirements? The problem is that testing is the validation and for that you need a requirements to check it against. The customer expectation are usually the high level requirements.

Comment: @Riawe: We're well outside my sphere of competence, but it looks to me like ISO 12207 is a completely different animal that's concerned with standardising/auditing the *software development process itself*, primarily ***within*** the software house. Only peripherally related to the issue under discussion here, which is more about whether the product is "fit for purpose" from the customer's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The first is to verify that every aspect of the requirements are handled in some way. This can happen before the product is finished. It just has to be clear that the working process are handling all aspects of the requirements.

The other is to validate (check/test) that all the functionality is working as the customer was expecting. This happen after there is a working version of the product.

Answer (score 0):

"***reflect*** the specified requirements": Ensure what the product does is what is required.
"*requirements are **fulfilled***": Ensure the product actual does what it attempts to do, satisfactorily and completely.

*Verification* checks whether the features match the requirements one to one, and all of them.
*Validation* checks whether the product actually achieves these.

Comment: Well, I cannot see the difference /language barrier?/. Ensure that it does what is required seems to be the same as the latter.

Comment: My answer should **cover** every point in your question and only those points, right? My answer should satisfactorily and fully **answer** the points, right? Are they different now?

Comment: The answer, unfortunately, for me as a non native speaker is that helpful - ensure it does what is required. Ensure it does what it attempts to do, completely. I would assume if it does what is required, than it is implicitly doing it completely.

Answer (score 0):

*Verification* is performed as a check to ensure that all the requirements have been *implemented*.

*Validation* is performed as a check to ensure that the implementation is *suitable for use*.

I may have had a requirement that says, "The product shall have a button to turn on the radio", and I can verify that the requirement has been implemented;  there is the button inside the trunk of the car, and when you press it the radio turns on.  But the implementation is not suitable for use-  the customer expected that when they were driving they'd be able to turn on the radio and they cannot.

As to your two sentences, the first talks about whether the work product reflects (implements) the specified requirements.  (Is there a button and does it work?)

The second talks about confirming that the product may be used *for a specific intended use*. (Can they use the radio while driving.)

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it is not like that. Verification check only the intermediate products like design, diagrams, or code. It checks whether it conforms to requirements (button should be there according the design doc, is there a code for that?)

Comment: @Riawe- Is that not what I said?  Verification checks that all requirements have been implemented- i.e., it checks whether the product conforms to requirements.

Comment: Well, verification does not check the final product, just the work products (design, code, docs). Validation, on the other hand, checks that final product conforms to requirement/works as intended

Answer (score -2):

From my humble point of view it looks like two stages of a process:

1. reflection
2. validation

Comment: Could you expand on this more? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.